# What is the meaning of the below probability equation?

Tags: probability-theory

Can someone explain the intuitive idea behind this probability equation (especially the part where the limit of epsilon downarrow zero notation).

[image: Probability]

Comment: The given probability is only $\ne 0$, if the random variable is discrete. In this case, it is the difference of the probability for the given value $x$ and that for all values below $x$. Since the distance between the possible values can be arbitary small, we have to use an $\epsilon$ going to $0$ to formulare this for any case.

Comment: Not exactly discrete, we could have for example density $\frac{1}{2}$ in the interval $(0,1)$, a point mass of $\frac{1}{6}$ **at** $x=1$, and density $\frac{1}{3}$ on $(1,2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $F(x) = Pr\{{X \leq x\}}$, so this is just saying that
$P\{{X=x\}} = lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}$ $F(x) - F(x-\epsilon) = lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}$ $P\{{X\leq x\}} - P\{{X \leq x -\epsilon\}}$

EDIT (thanks to David K): This is assumed to be a one-sided limit. The reason being that $P\{{X\leq x\}} - P\{{X \leq x -\epsilon\}}$ when evaluated for $\epsilon < 0$ will be negative (due to the monotonicity of the Cumulative Probability function).

Comment: Oh! I see. So the probability $P(X = x)$ is equal to $F(x) - F(x - \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a very small value, right?

Comment: @Jay_987 Equal to the *limit* as you make $\epsilon$ closer and closer to zero, yes.

Comment: I think the downward arrow indicates a one-sided limit (only positive $\epsilon$ is considered). I am more accustomed to seeing this written $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}$.

Comment: Thanks @DavidK I made a note containing a comment on ... your comment

Answer (score 0):

Consider a binomial distribution. $X~B(0.5,6)$ for example. Then $p(X)=2$ is the same as $p(X\le2)-p(X\le1)$. The formula is doing an analogous thing for a continuous distribution by evaluating its cumulative distribution function at close values of $x$. The approximation of $p(x)$ improving as the points get closer.

Comment: I see. That makes more sense to me now. Thanks for pointing out that this is a continuous distribution! I didn't notice that before.